# While statement in c goes into infinite loop when float value is assigned to int?

Tags: c, while-loop, floating-point, integer, infinite-loop

So this is the code:

```
int num, counter = 1;

while (counter == 1)
{
    printf_s("Enter a 5-digit integer :");
    scanf_s("%d",&num);

    if (num < 10000 || num > 99999)
    {
        puts("Please make sure the number you entered has 5 digits!\n");
    }
    else if((num%100000 - num%10000)/10000 == num%10 && (num%100-num%10) == (num%10000-num%1000)/100 )
    {
        printf_s("%d is a 5-digit palindrome!\n",num);
        puts("Do you wish to continue? 1 = continue 0 = stop");
        scanf_s("%d",&counter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("%d is not a palindrome!\n",num);
    }
}
```

I didn't expect it to do anything useful with floats since I didn't add anything for it to do so, but why does it enter an infinite loop saying "Enter a 5 digit integer : (number) isn't a palindrome!"?

edit: Turns out I forgot to add what type of variable num and counter was. And somehow called while a function.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: I recommend you forget that `scanf` (and `scanf_s`) even exists. Instead use e.g. `fgets` to read whole lines as strings. The muse e.g. `sscanf` to parse the string, or `strtoul` or `strtod`. And if you use `sscanf` always check what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: What type is `counter`?

Comment: @Iamme "when float value is assigned to int?" hints at a mis-understanding.  All user input is text, not `int`, `float`, etc.  The text is converted to `int`, `float` via `scanf()` depending on the specifiers.  When non-conforming text for a type is entered, problem text remains in `stdin`.  Use `fgets()` for all input until you know why `scanf()` is weak.

Comment: `while` is not a function

Answer (score 3):

> While function in c goes into infinite loop when float value is assigned to int?

Code fails to check the return value of `scanf_s("%d",&num);`

When non-numeric text for an `int`, like "123.456" is entered, `num` takes on the value `123` and 1 is returned.  The `'.'` is not consumed.  `scanf_s("%d",&num);` repeatedly fails on subsequent calls as it attempts to read ".456".  and `num` is not changed - infinite loop.

Instead, check the return value of input functions.

```
// scanf_s("%d",&num);
if (scanf_s("%d",&num) != 1) {
  puts("Fail");
  break;
}
```

Or use `fgets()` to read an entire line (usually). [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624692/while-function-in-c-goes-into-infinite-loop-when-float-value-is-assigned-to-int/73624830#comment130012779_73624692)

Comment: Thanks! Then should I take num in as a float first then convert to int when I have to use it?

Comment: @Iamme, No.  Take input in as a _string_ and fail it if it does not well convert into an `int`.  There is no reason for `float` - or any floating point type, in this code.

Comment: @Iamme, I am curious, why did you consider `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: I simply didn't think of it lol, I've never had to do anything that requires that much precision or space since I'm a beginner. I guess I should use it if I ever have to use a floating point variable to get into the habit?

Comment: I just ran a test on `scanf`. For `123.456` I _thought_ it would return -1. But it returns 1 and `num` will be `123`. It also does the same for `123x`. Then, I realized that is probably wants for `scanf` with _file_ input. But, given the context of checking for _valid_ user input (from `stdin`), I'd say that's bad and I'd use `strtol` with the requisite checks instead.

Comment: @CraigEstey Notes: "thought it would return -1" --> It returns 1 and `num == 123` as you well observed, yet `".456"` remains in `stdin` as the next input.  _usually_ this is not desired.  Returning `EOF` occurs when no input and end-of-file occurs ( and some other cases).  Same scenario if reading from a file with `fscanf()`.  IMW, `scanf()` would have a specifier to detect and/or consume the rest of the _line_.

Comment: @Iamme If FP needed, use `double` in C unless you know of a compelling reason to use other FP types.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test on `scanf`.

For `123.456` I *thought* it would return -1. But it returns 1 and `num` will be `123`. It also does the same for `123x`.

Then, I realized that is probably wants for `scanf` with *file* input.

But, given the context of checking for *valid* user input (from `stdin`), I'd say that's bad and I'd use `strtol` with the requisite checks instead.

---

Here's some code that shows the difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void
doscanf(const char *str)
{
    int ret;
    int num;

    errno = 0;
    ret = sscanf(str,"%d",&num);

    printf("doscanf: str='%s' ret=%d num=%d -- %s\n",
        str,ret,num,strerror(errno));
}

void
dostrtol(const char *str)
{

    errno = 0;

    char *cp;
    int num = strtol(str,&cp,10);
    int valid = (*cp == 0);

    printf("dostrtol: num=%d str='%s' cp='%s' valid=%d -- %s\n",
        num,str,cp,valid,strerror(errno));
}

int
main(void)
{
    const char *strs[] = {
        "123",
        "456",
        "",
        "123.456",
        "123x",
        "x123",
        NULL,
    };

    int sep = 0;
    for (const char **str = strs;  *str != NULL;  ++str) {
        if (sep)
            printf("\n");
        sep = 1;

        doscanf(*str);
        dostrtol(*str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
doscanf: str='123' ret=1 num=123 -- Success
dostrtol: num=123 str='123' cp='' valid=1 -- Success

doscanf: str='456' ret=1 num=456 -- Success
dostrtol: num=456 str='456' cp='' valid=1 -- Success

doscanf: str='' ret=-1 num=1 -- Success
dostrtol: num=0 str='' cp='' valid=1 -- Success

doscanf: str='123.456' ret=1 num=123 -- Success
dostrtol: num=123 str='123.456' cp='.456' valid=0 -- Success

doscanf: str='123x' ret=1 num=123 -- Success
dostrtol: num=123 str='123x' cp='x' valid=0 -- Success

doscanf: str='x123' ret=0 num=0 -- Success
dostrtol: num=0 str='x123' cp='x123' valid=0 -- Success
```

---

*Side note:* Your "is palindrome" algorithm is *hardwired* to take only 5 digit numbers.

That's okay, but a bit restrictive (and unusual). Here's a test program that shows a generalized algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// orig -- OP original code (restricted/hardwired to 5 digit numbers)
int
orig(int num)
{
    int palflg;

    palflg = (num%100000 - num%10000)/10000 == num%10 &&
        (num%100-num%10) == (num%10000-num%1000)/100;

    return palflg;
}

// ispal -- generalized to any number
int
ispal(int num)
{
    int digits[100];
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int palflg = 1;

    // split number into digits
    for (;  num != 0;  num /= 10)
        digits[right++] = num % 10;

    // compare outer digits (working inward)
    --right;
    for (;  left <= right;  ++left, --right) {
        palflg = (digits[left] == digits[right]);
        if (! palflg)
            break;
    }

    return palflg;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int numbers[] = {
        12345, 12312, 12321, 56465,
#ifndef RESTRICT
        0, 1, 23, 123, 232, 1221, 12321, 123321,
#endif
    };

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);  ++idx) {
        int num = numbers[idx];

        int palflg = ispal(num);
        int origflg = orig(num);

        printf("%10d -- ispal=%s orig=%s -- %s\n",
            num,
            palflg ? "is" : "not",
            origflg ? "is" : "not",
            (palflg == origflg) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
     12345 -- ispal=not orig=not -- PASS
     12312 -- ispal=not orig=not -- PASS
     12321 -- ispal=is orig=is -- PASS
     56465 -- ispal=is orig=is -- PASS
         0 -- ispal=is orig=is -- PASS
         1 -- ispal=is orig=not -- FAIL
        23 -- ispal=not orig=not -- PASS
       123 -- ispal=not orig=not -- PASS
       232 -- ispal=is orig=not -- FAIL
      1221 -- ispal=is orig=not -- FAIL
     12321 -- ispal=is orig=is -- PASS
    123321 -- ispal=is orig=not -- FAIL
```